# How do I test my internet connection speed via a Microsoft Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, latency

I currently have two production servers. One running Windows Server 2003 and the other Windows Server 2008. When I open the `Reliability and Performance Monitor` I see a `Network` section that only goes up to `56Kbps` see the image below.

[image]

It concerns me that 56Kpbs is the maximum bandwidth that our database server has available. This server is located on the other side of the world, and I have no way of physically accessing the network hardware. I've been instructed not to browse the internet on this computer or download things like adobe flash. This prevents me from doing a simple internet upload and download speed test.

How do I test the servers internet speed from the Microsoft Windows command line or equivalent that does not involve opening a browser on the server? I might be permitted to securely transfer a program after it is scanned for viruses to the server, but this is the least desirable option.

Comment: The graphs for everything except CPU are scaled. Your server's maximum bandwidth isn't 56kbps, that's just the highest measurement taken in the sample shown.

Comment: @JamesSneeringer That is good news. However, how do I determine my network speed?

Comment: You can use tools like iperf, qcheck, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Invoke-WebRequest http://speedtest.newark.linode.com/100MB-newark.bin -OutFile $env:TEMP`

Comment: Good answer, but this is only for Powershell v3 or above, which the op won't have unless they have explicitly installed it on those servers. Also dumping to `c:\` normally can't be done unless you're running from an elevated ps shell. Easy fixed.

Comment: It seems that Powershell v2 is available for Windows Server 2003 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4045 but I've been unable to find a higher version of Powershell that is compatible with Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Apparently, you can use Powershell 2.0 to install Powershell 3.0. This is according to Tyler's comment on this page http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/05/powershell-3-0-is-now-available-for-download.aspx  Still I am reluctant to try this on a production server as it is unclear whether the upgrade will succeed on Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2.

Comment: @nueverest yeah I wouldn't be touching a production 2003 server with Powershell. Way too much risk for a system that's EOL.

Comment: I'm experimenting with this command on a Windows 8.1 machine and I'm getting `Access to the path 'C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp' is denied.`

Comment: @nueverest you need to put a filename on the end, eg $env:TEMP\mb.bin

Comment: The main issue we've found with this command line is that it can be limited by the CPU in the server. Haven't found a better solution though